# Changing the scheduling type for process in android

Tags: android, renice

I want my application to get highest priority and time slice it needs from system.
For this I changed the priority of my android process using renice command I am able to set the priority.
Would like to understand what all scheduling types are accepted?

Note- already checked with http://www.all-things-android.com/content/android-toolbox-command-reference

Comment: Please try to reword your question because I'm not able to comprehend what you are asking for.

Comment: I have a NDK application running on android I want it to get the highest priority and want to change scheduling type. renice command in adb shell can set priority and scheduling method I referred to above link to change priority also

Comment: I have a NDK application running on android I want it to get the highest priority and want to change scheduling type. renice command in adb shell can set priority and scheduling method, I referred to above link to change priority(renice [-r] [-t <type>] <priority> <pids ...>). Using option -t i can set scheduling type. I wanted to know what all are types. Two values which I saw are RR and FIFO. You can see the value of SCHED change on setting these values on input ps -p -t in adb shell.